# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, compilation, report

I am building a school management which needs to include terminal reports. I am using jasperreports but when I  run the codes in intellij, the reports are shown. But when I create the jar file and run the it, this is the error i encounter from the console .

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException

Comment: Make sure your dependencies are built into the final jar. What are you using to build the jar?

Comment: Ben,  The jar is built using the normal way intellij makes a jar. I just  go to project structure in intelllij and  try  to create a new  artifact. Then I count the dependencies to see if they are the same as  those in the tested project.

Comment: Is there another way of building the jar? And how do I verify that dependencies are  being built in the final jar file? Thanks.

Comment: These are the dependencies that appear under 'external libraries' in my project and also the dependencies that appear when creating the artifact   : com.lowagie.text-2.1.7
commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0
commons-digester-2.1
commons-logging-1.1.1
itextpdf-5.5.1
jasperreports-5.0.1
org.apache.commons.beanutils
poi-5.0

Comment: To make sure IDE added all needed dependencies, you can open the .jar file as an archive and check inside. 
Please post your project structure screenshot.

Comment: thanks Annikov for your suggestion.  I just solved the problem. After 3 days without sleep(not even for 5 minutes), trying to solve this problem so that I can make enough money to rent a place

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.

1. I switched IDEs. I was using intellij all this while and all this nonsense was going on. I checked their documentation but to no use. I switched to Netbeans and  the problem was resolved within less than 5 minutes. So if you are using one IDE, try another.
2. I used the same version of jasper reports in netbeans as was used in the jasper studio. So if the version of the jasperreports is 6.17 in the studio, please download and use the same version in your program.

Comment: The problem is not the IDE, the problem is because the jasper version is different between the maven library and jasper studio used to compile the report.